# how to create executable shell script that can be executed in windows and Unix OS

Tags: bash, shell-script

I want to know how to create a package of my small BMI script created using shell script so that I can run the executable script on any platform : windows and Linux

I am not getting a correct source so need to post it as question

I installed oracle on my windows PC , I just went inside the system file their I can see most of the things are written using shell script

But how this script is running on Windows , even though it is created in Unix that's my question
can anyone tell me how it is done

for example : I write a script in Unix and want to create executable file , once I put it on my windows then it should run

Answer (score 0):

If you have Windows 10 or Windows Server 2019, than you can use [WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux). This [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) shows you how to install WSL on Windows 10. When you have WSL installed, you can run any Linux script you want.

Other alternative is using [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl). You can install [the multi-platform binary](https://www.tcl-lang.org).

Other option is using [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell). It is currently supported on [Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux)